# Wiki Link Mapper — A webcrawler which crawls links recursively and prints them into a graph

Tags: python, graph, web-scraping, data-visualization, wikipedia

I would like some suggestions on how to make it better and also if any features that i should add to this Script. I am using beautifulsoup,requests for scraping and networkx for plotting the graph.

https://github.com/HardikM1999/WikiLinkMapper

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Taking Arguments
#Starting string
start = sys.argv[1]

#No of repetitions
rep = int(sys.argv[2])
tot_list = []

#Creating graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(start)

#recur function to scrape links
def recur(url,depth,tot_list,parent,rep):
    if(depth<=rep):
        page = requests.get('https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + url)
        #parsing the page
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
        cnt = 0
        #list for particular depth
        depth_list = []
        for para_tag in soup.select('p'):
            for anchor_tag in para_tag.select('a'):
                if cnt>rep:
                    break
                #getting the link
                check_string = anchor_tag['href']
                if check_string.startswith('#cite') == False and check_string.startswith('/wiki/Help') == False and check_string.startswith('/wiki///en:') == False and check_string.startswith('/wiki/Wikipedia') == False :
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                    depth_list.append(check_string[6:])
            if cnt>rep:
                break
        for link in depth_list:
            tot_list.append((link,parent))  
            recur(link,depth+1,tot_list,link,rep)
    return tot_list


tot_list = recur(start,0,tot_list,start,rep)
node_sizes = []
node_sizes.append(100*len(start))

#Adding tot_list to the graph
for a,b in tot_list:
    G.add_node(a)
    G.add_edge(a,b)
    node_sizes.append(100*len(a))

#Drawing the Graph
nx.draw(G,node_color = 'orange',node_size = node_sizes,with_labels = True)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia contains circular references. Currently you follow them around until your max depth is reached. Instead, keep a `set` of all sites visited so far.

You also don't need this function to be recursive, you can make it iterative like this:

```
from collections import deque

def build_link_graph(start, max_pages=10):
    queue = deque([start])
    visited = set()
    i = 0
    while queue and i < max_pages:
        next_url = queue.popleft()
        urls = get_links(next_url)
        i += 1
        # make sure not to visit any page twice
        queue.extend(url for url in urls if url not in visited)  
        visited.update(urls)
        yield next_url, urls
```

The actual parsing can also be simplified using the [CSS selector `p > a`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp), meaning all `a` tags which are contained in a `p` tag. I would also use a [`requests.Session`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to keep the connection alive and use the [`lxml` parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), both of which slightly speed up the scraping.

```
def filter_links(links):
    blacklist = ['#cite', '/wiki/Help', '/wiki///en:', '/wiki/Wikipedia']                                   
    return [link for link in links                    
            if not any(link.startswith(prefix) for prefix in blacklist)]

def get_links(url):
    page = SESSION.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
    links = [a["href"]
             for a in soup.select("p > a")
             if "selflink" not in a.get("class", [])]
    return [BASE_URL + link for link in filter_links(links)]
```

With these functions, building the graph is rather easy. Note that you might want to choose a directed graph, since links are usually unidirectional. Also, `networkx` automatically adds missing nodes when adding edges, so no need to do that.

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BASE_URL = "'https://en.wikipedia.org'"
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        start = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        start = BASE_URL + '/wiki/Earthquake_engineering'
    SESSION = requests.Session()
    g = nx.DiGraph()
    for url, urls in build_link_graph(start):
        graph.add_edges_from((url, link) for link in urls)
```

I added a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script from another script without running the scraping

---

Note that if you increase `max_pages` too much, you will run into a too many requests.response. Currently there is no code to handle that, but you might add some. The easiest way is to just `time.sleep` some time and try again afterwards. There are also other ways, some of which may not be in compliance with Wikipedia's ToS:

```
# robots.txt for Wikipedia and friends
# Please note: There are a lot of pages on this site, and there are
# some misbehaved spiders out there that go _way_ too fast. If you're
# irresponsible, your access to the site may be blocked.
```

There may be other ways to build this graph than scraping. Wikipedia supplies databases to download which should contain everything you need: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download Note that it is 58 GB when uncompressed, though.